# Add Ajax Timer Control in Master Page

Tags: c#

Hai frnds..How to add the Ajax Timer Control in Master Page. Its Possible? In my application I added but the event is not fired. can any one help me plz

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to use standard javascipt intervals to initiate ajax events? We will need more info on the problem.

You could try something like:

when page loads call, showAlert()

```
function showAlert()
{
    alert("Hello Users");
    setTimeout('showAlert()', 10000);
}
```

Comment: for every 10 sec i want update the message to users in alert box. i don't want to refresh full page just one method i have to update every 10 sec automatically.